# VMWare VIM SDK. List all VM's working, but list all datasources does not. Am I missing something?

Tags: vmware

My goal is to get a listing of all the DataStores in a specific datacenter.  I'm able to list all of the Hosts, and VM's, but not the Datastores, and I don't understand why (I'm still learning the API's).  Any insight would be appreciated.

Here's the code for grabbing all of the VM's (this works as expected):

```
public List<VM> getVMsInDatacenter(String datacenter, IEnumerable<String> properties)
{
  List<VM> VMs = null;

  this.joinConnection((appUtil) =>
  {
    var svcUtil = appUtil.getServiceUtil();
    var dcMoRef = svcUtil.GetDecendentMoRef(null, "Datacenter", datacenter);

    var typeinfo = buildTypeInfo("VirtualMachine", properties.ToList());

    VMs = buildVMsFromObjectContent(svcUtil.GetContentsRecursively(null, dcMoRef, typeinfo, true));
  });
  return VMs;
}
```

Here is the analogous code for the Datastore (which does not work as expected):

```
public List<DataStore> getDataStoresInDatacenter(String datacenter, IEnumerable<String> properties)
{
  List<DataStore> DataStores = null;

  this.joinConnection((appUtil) =>
  {
    var svcUtil = appUtil.getServiceUtil();
    var dcMoRef = svcUtil.GetDecendentMoRef(null, "Datacenter", datacenter);

    var typeinfo = buildTypeInfo("Datastore", properties.ToList());

    DataStores = buildDataStoresFromObjectContent(svcUtil.GetContentsRecursively(null, dcMoRef, typeinfo, true));
  });
  return DataStores;
}
```

appUtil is an instantiation of the AppUtil class that came with the VIM SDK samples.  It houses functionality for connecting, querying, etc.

joinConnection is a method for connecting, or re-using a connection if we've already connected.

If there are any other questions about the code, please let me know.

Also, if there's a better way, I'd like to know that too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.  The method getContentsRecursively is calling a method called 'buildFullTraversal' that builds a traversal/selection spec.  This method was not adding a traversal for the datastore.  I added one that like so:

```
TraversalSpec vmToDs = new TraversalSpec();
  vmToDs.name = "vmToDs";
  vmToDs.type = "VirtualMachine";
  vmToDs.path = "datastore";
  HToVm.skip = false;
  HToVm.skipSpecified = true;
```

And then I modified the visitFolders traversal like so:

```
// Recurse through the folders
  TraversalSpec visitFolders = new TraversalSpec();
  visitFolders.name = "visitFolders";
  visitFolders.type = "Folder";
  visitFolders.path = "childEntity";
  visitFolders.skip = false;
  visitFolders.skipSpecified = true;
  visitFolders.selectSet = new SelectionSpec[] { new SelectionSpec(), new SelectionSpec(), new SelectionSpec(), new SelectionSpec(), new SelectionSpec(), new SelectionSpec(), new SelectionSpec(), new SelectionSpec() };
  visitFolders.selectSet[0].name = "visitFolders";
  visitFolders.selectSet[1].name = "dcToHf";
  visitFolders.selectSet[2].name = "dcToVmf";
  visitFolders.selectSet[3].name = "crToH";
  visitFolders.selectSet[4].name = "crToRp";
  visitFolders.selectSet[5].name = "HToVm";
  visitFolders.selectSet[6].name = "rpToVm";
  visitFolders.selectSet[7].name = "vmToDs";
  return new SelectionSpec[] { visitFolders, dcToVmf, dcToHf, crToH, crToRp, rpToRp, HToVm, rpToVm, vmToDs };
```

Now, calls to getContentsRecursively will also include the datastores that belong to a VM, so the method in the question will works as expected.